# pointPolygonTest doesn't find any point

Tags: c++, opencv, contour, gestures, convex-polygon

I want to find center of palm. Firstly,I found contours and select max area contour. And I used pointPolygonTest. My code and result image are below, but I didn't find any point using pointPolygonTest. What is the problem?

```
double dist, maxdist = -1;
    Point center;
    for(int i = 0; i< drawing.cols; i += 10) {
        for(int j = 0; j< drawing.rows; j += 10) {

            dist = pointPolygonTest(contours[maxAreaIndex], Point(i,j),true);
            cout << "   dist " << dist << endl;
            if(dist > maxdist)
            {
                maxdist = dist;
                center = cv::Point(i,j);
            }
        }
    }
    cout << "maxdist = " << maxdist << endl;
    circle(drawing, center, maxdist, cv::Scalar(220,75,20),1,CV_AA);
    /// Show in a window
    namedWindow( "Contours", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    imshow( "Contours", drawing );
```

[image]

Comment: Why are i,j in the range 1..10?

Comment: When I used +1,it was too slow.

Comment: Should you pass contours rather than contours[maxAreaIndex] to pointPolygonTest? How is it defined?

Comment: I used this definition vector<vector<Point> > contours; And I calculated max area after findContours(...) function.  int maxAreaIndex = 0;

 for( int i = 1; i< contours.size(); i++ )
 {
  area = fabs(contourArea(contours[i]));
  if (area > max_area) {
   max_area = area;
   maxAreaIndex = i;
  }
 }